# Does a dart broadcast `StreamController` support multiple producers?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

Can I have multiple asynchronous operations that call `controller.add(myEvent)` on a single broadcast [`StreamController`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-async/StreamController-class.html)? In other words, can I have multiple producers that emit stream events on the same broadcast stream?

The reason for this question is because [the documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.broadcast.html) states that it s

> not allowed to call add, addError, or close before a previous call has returned.

However, `add` is a synchronous operation that returns `void` (rather than a `Future`). How am I to understand this statement?

Comment: most likely it means you cannot call them from different isolates (threads)

Comment: @pskink What are the practical implications of this in a flutter application? Do I have to take special precautions when calling `controller.add`?

Comment: if you don't use any isolates you should not worry about imho